# Next.js dynamic route - 404 on page reload after added SLUG

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm used Next.js and Node.js for my project.

What we have:
Pages structure:

pages/products/PageSomeName.js

pages/products/PageEnotherName.js

pages/products/PageName.js

Pages name in **products** folder is can be different

**routes.js**

```
routes.add("/products/:id", "/products/[id].js");
```

**server.js**

```
app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.use(
    "./images",
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images"), {
      maxAge: dev ? "0" : "365d"
    })
  );

  server.use(bodyParser.json());

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9001;

  server.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Read on http://${process.env.SITE_URL_FULL}`);
  });
});
```

**Link component**

```
 <Link href={`/products/${data.link}`} as={`/products/${data.slug}`}/>
```

**data array**

```
export const storeProducts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Title1",
    link: "product_name_some",
    slug: "product-1-slug",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Title2",
    link: "product_name_different_some_name",
    slug: "product-2-slug"
  },
```

**There was a problem when I added slug for my links.**

By client side everything works fine. I take localhost:3000/product-2-slug  in browser url.  But after reload, I take 404 error page from Next.js

What I must added by server side in server.js for normal server reloading? 
Maybe I need change Link component or next-route settings in **routes.js**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In **server.js** you should have a routes as below.

```
server.get("/products/product1", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
});
```

```
server.get("/products/product2", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
});
```

```
server.get("/products/product3", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
});
```

A good way to handle the same is to create a generic **products.js** inside the **pages** directory and on server handle as below.

**server.js**

```
server.get("/products/:id", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res, { id: req.params.id });
});
```

and in

**pages/products.js** we can create a **getInitialProps** method

```
static getInitialProps (context) {
    // parameters reqturned from server are accessible via
    const id = ctx.query.id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I changed a little description of the problem. Files in a folder can be of different name, end I need add slug parameter to Link for  everyone products. By client side everything works fine, I take url fir slug, but after reload page I take 404.

Comment: Hi @Pawel Gronski, did you find the solution to this problem?